# How to get Current URl from currently opened browser to my app?

Tags: android

Is there any way to get Current browsing url to my app?Pls help me.In my app i want to get current browsing url from currently opened browser.I'm using android studio to develop my app.

Comment: you mean, if user browse somthing in another app like UCBrowser  and you want to get that url in you app?

Comment: Yes bro,you are correct

Comment: okay but its very hard to say its possible because 3rd party app does not provide user browsing history for privacy policy and security concern

Comment: Ok bro.can we able to do this in chrome browser bro

Comment: You need to give more time for it -
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23199/where-does-the-standard-android-web-browser-keep-its-history-files

Comment: Ok bro,pls tell me when you get it.

Answer (score -1):

If you have an instance of the `webView` simply use:

```
webView.getUrl()
```

You can use `findViewById` to get an instance of the `webView`.

Comment: Bro i want to get current browsing url ,for example while using chrome i want to get current browsing url in my app bro